# Submit listbox data to sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I wrote this code a few months ago (with the help of folks here) to handle data submission to an Excel sheet.

Today everything still works apart the list box submission. I get the confirmation to say that the data has been input to the sheet. That is true apart from the data in the listbox, nothing is submitted to the sheet.

The only thing that has changed from my end is my work environment has recently been moved to SharePoint.

This is the entire code.

```vb
Private Sub Production_Submit_Click()

    Sheets("Sales Order Log").Unprotect Password:="XstrahlSalesOrderLog"

    'Locks all fields within the form and also displays a msgbox informing the user of this if trying to submit information to the sheet within inputting a Sales Order Number
    If SalesOrderProd = "" Then
        WorkOrderNo.Locked = True
        ProdDesc.Locked = True
        ProdDate.Locked = True
        ProdComplete.Locked = True
        MsgBox "Please insert a Sales Order Number to continue", vbCritical, "Missing Sales Order Number"
        Exit Sub
    Else
        WorkOrderNo.Locked = False
        ProdDesc.Locked = False
        ProdDate.Locked = False
        ProdComplete.Locked = False
    End If

    Dim Reference As String
    Dim wkord As String

    Reference = Trim(SalesOrderProd.Text)
    LastRow = Worksheets("Sales Order Log").Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 To LastRow

        'Submits the Production information to the sheet
        If Worksheets("Sales Order Log").Cells(i, 2).Value = Reference Then
            'Worksheets("Sales Order Log").Cells(i, 10).Value = WorkOrderNo
            Worksheets("Sales Order Log").Cells(i, 13).Value = ProdDesc
            Worksheets("Sales Order Log").Cells(i, 14).Value = ProdDate
            Worksheets("Sales Order Log").Cells(i, 15).Value = ProdComplete

            If WkOrderList.ListIndex <> -1 Then
                For j = LBound(Me.WkOrderList.List) To UBound(Me.WkOrderList.List)
                    wkord = wkord & IIf(wkord = "", "", vbNewLine) & Me.WkOrderList.List(j, 0)

                    With Sheets("Sales Order Log").Range("Sales_Data_Start")
                        ' .Offset(TargetRow, 1).Value = SalesOrderNo
                        ' (...)
                        Worksheets("Sales Order Log").Cells(i, 12).Value = wkord
                    End With
                Next
            End If
        End If
    Next

    'Displays a message box informing the user that the form information has been input into the spreadsheet
    MsgBox "Information added to Sales Order: " & SalesOrderProd & " successfully", vbInformation, "Production"

    'Blanks the form once information has been submitted to the sheet
    SalesOrderProd.Value = ""
    WorkOrderNo.Value = ""
    ProdDesc.Value = ""
    ProdDate.Value = ""
    ProdComplete.Value = ""
    WkOrderList.Clear

    Sheets("Sales Order Log").Protect Password:="XstrahlSalesOrderLog"

End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code `(F8)` to see what's going on?

Comment: Not part of your issue, but perhaps you should be moving the "unlock worksheet" code to *after* the "check if code should run" bit?  As it stands, running the code with no Sales Number will unlock the sheet but not relock it.

Comment: @Chronocidal thanks for that, oversight on my part.

Comment: @CLR I have yes, nothing is amiss, the code is exactly as I left it months ago.

Comment: @Strexxin But in stepping through it, you should be able to spot why (or at least where) the code fails.

Comment: I also suggest stepping though and opening the Watch window. Add a watcher for each variable. After every few lines, scroll through the watch window and see if the values line up to what you're expecting.

Comment: I have found that the error comes from this line "If WkOrderList.ListIndex <> -1 Then"

If I comment it out then the listbox data posts to the sheet fine, it just means I get an error if someone tries to submit data to the sheet if the listbox is empty

Comment: Sounds like you need to add an `Else` to that `If` statement to handle that case. Perhaps a `MsgBox` to the user to remind them to make a selection.

Comment: To add even more mystery to the pot, If I add values to the listbox and then post the data the listbox data is not posted. If however I add a value to the listbox, delete it and re-add it the data in the listbox posts to the sheet just fine. It is as if the listbox is not acknowledged as existing until something is added and then removed from it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`If WkOrderList.ListIndex <> -1` doesn't test if the list box is empty as you suggest you expect (in a comment).  It tests if something is selected in the list.

To test for not empty, use

```
If Me.WkOrderList.ListCount > 0
```